# unable to install r - studio?

Tags: installation, rstudio

I hope you can help me.
Last Tuesday I did a fresh installation of R-Studio.
When I startup R-Studio we are getting a startup error.

The R session failed to start.
The R session process exited with code 10.

[image]

Comment: Do you have R installed?

Comment: Also see here for a possible solution: https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-studio-doesnt-link-with-r-exiting-with-code-10/108696

Comment: @Phil thanks a lot ..it's started working fine now .